# Scales percent function cannot cope with accuracy argument

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I need to compute percentages for my valueboxes. However, when I'm computing the percentages and adding an accuracy argument, the console gives an error. To illustrate my problem, an example with the same sort of code is given below.

```
library(scales)
x <- 235.53
y <- 928.32
proc <- x / y
scales::percent(proc, accurary = 0.01)
```

both

```
scales::percent(proc, accurary = 0.01)
```

and

```
percent(proc, accurary = 0.01)
```

do not work.

The following errors are obtained

```
Error in scales::percent(perc, accuracy = 0.01) :
  unused argument (accuracy = 0.01)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: typo in `accuracy`

Comment: Sorry, fixed it and I still have the same problem

Comment: okay, then I can't reproduce, sorry. Try restarting R, and try again, making sure that `accuracy` is used instead of `accurary`. If you still get an issue can you add the results of `sessionInfo()` to your question please.

Comment: I had to reinstall to get it working.